# How can I set capital letter is same with lowercase letter for counting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The assignment is counting a specific letter in a string.
But the problem is that I don't know how to set capital letter is same with lowercase letter.
For example, There are three 'a' in 'aAa', a string.

my code is working well if it distinguishes capital letter and lowercase letter.

```
function countChar(string, char) {

  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

    if (string[i] === char) {
      count = count + 1;
    }

  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert both strings to lower case in advance with [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). The other way is possible as well by using [`String#toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

Both methods returns a comparable result.

```
char = char.toLowerCase();
string = string.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to lower case using

```
.toLowerCase()
```

```js
function countChar(string, char) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  char=char.toLowerCase();
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === char) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countChar('aAa', 'A'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just solved it :)))))

Comment: @ellipsis `countChar('aAa', 'A')` returns `0`

Comment: @User863 made an edit

Answer (score 0):

In one line you can do:

```js
function countChar(string, char) {
  return string.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((count , x) => (x === char ? count+1 : count), 0);
}

console.log(countChar('aAa', 'a'))
```